# why k8s deployment hpa doesn't calculate istio/sidecar 's cpu request

Tags: kubernetes, cpu, code-injection, hpa

i set hpa for my deployment/app, for example, CPU 80%.

my app deployment has two containers, one is app for traffic, the other is automatically injected istio-proxy.

when i get hpa during running traffic, i found something unexpected for the hpa result.

the cpu request of istio-proxy is 2G.
the cpu request of app is 4G.
the cpu consumed of istio-proxy is 1G.
the cpu consumed of app is 4G.

so, i expected the hpa of this pod (including 2 containers) is (1+2)/(2+4) = 50%.

but the actual result is close to (1+2)/4 = 75%.

it seems the istio-proxy's cpu request is excluded from calculating cpu utilization of hpa.

as i know, k8s get cpu requests from deployment, but actually for this sidecar auto injection case, the deployment yaml doesn't have any istio-proxy container information.

i guess that's why the istio-proxy cpu request is excluded.
but is that the expected behavior or a bug ?

Comment: You're talking about cpu requests in GB... You mean memory requests, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think as of 1.19, the hpa works on an average value of all containers in the pods. The exact logic is here : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.0/pkg/controller/podautoscaler/metrics/utilization.go#L49

```
currentUtilization = int32((metricsTotal * 100) / requestsTotal)
```

As per the above logic HPA is calculating pod cpu utilization as total cpu usage of all containers in pod divided by total request